# How do I change property files in a SoapUI test step?

Tags: groovy, properties, soapui

So let's say I have a properties file called Ben with these properties:

```
name: Ben
hair: blond
eyes: red
```

I have imported this properties file into a properties test step manually by typing out its relative path into the test step. Then I have a test case that inputs the name from the file and makes sure that the output it gets back is the correct hair and eyes. Now, I want to test more than just one person. Let's say I have another properties file named Jake:

```
name: Jake
hair: black
eyes: blue
```

If I want to switch the properties file, the only way I know how is to manually input this property file's path when I want to run a new test. Is there any way for me to implement a Groovy script that will automatically cycle through the different properties files in the properties test step? That way I can hit run, and it will be able to test all of the properties instead of having to run each properties files individually.

Comment: Couple questions: Do you use soapui pro? Are all the property file paths known?

Comment: No it's not pro. Yes, the file paths are known.

Comment: I gave an answer that should help.

Comment: I am not associated with SoapUI, and I do not make commission off them, but the few hundred bucks is totally worth it! See this for your problem: http://www.soapui.org/Data-Driven-Testing/functional-tests.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The follow should be what you are looking for:

First create a new Global Property named something like "fileName".

```
(File -> Preferences -> Global Properties)
```

Create a Groovy Script Test Step:

```
import com.eviware.soapui.SoapUI

def fileNames = ["Ben","Jack","Joe"]

for (i in fileNames){
     SoapUI.getGlobalProperties().getProperty('fileName').setValue(i)
    testRunner.runTestStepByName("testStepNameHere")
}
```

Then on in the property file path put the dynamic property value.

Example:

```
C:/trunk/directory/Ben.txt
```

would become...

```
C:/trunk/directory/${fileName}.txt
```

You will want to consider the order of your teststeps and perhaps want to disable the teststep you call out to be ran in the script. This is the SOAPUI approach. If you had SOAPUI Pro this could be done a lot cleaner because of the datasource/loop teststeps.

I hope this helps.